# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to Category

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Here's my model

```
public class Category
{
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public Category Parent { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Children)
        .WithOptional(y => y.Parent)
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentId"));
```

Here's how I add data to it:

```
 var a = new List<Category>
 {
   new Category { Description = "Animals" }
   new Category { Description = "Dog", Parent = 1 } <<<-ERROR
 }
 a.ForEach(s => context.Categories.Add(s));
 context.SaveChanges();
```

How can I add the CategoryId from the 1st row to the second row???

Sorry, I think this is a very basic question, but I cant figure out how to do it

Thanks

Comment: *I* assume you're wanting "Dog"'s parent to be "Animals". What makes *you* assume that "Animals" will be the `Category` with `CategoryId` 1?

Comment: yes you're right, dog's parent will be animal. caategoryId is autonumber. sorry If my sample doesnt make sense. this is just a test data, not the actual code im using. let me know if you need more details. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cant use 1, because 1 is an integer and not of the type Category. You need to declare the category outside the lists declaration and add it to the list later:

```
List<Category> list = new List<Category>();
Category a = new Category();
Category b = new Category(){ Parent = a};

list.Add(a);
list.Add(b);
```

Note that this is just some code I made up and I didnt test it, but you get the idea!

Comment: Looks about right (I don't know EF, but this seems to be a more fundamental issue about parenting an object)

Comment: thank you M.Schenkel. still I don't know how to incorporate this to my adding method. I only have few weeks experience using EF and c#. I hope If you don't mind please provide me a sample on how to do it, will greatly appreciate it. thanks

Comment: Sure, could you provide your full add method? Based on that, I will supply a suggestion :)

Comment: @M.Schenkel, the full method is exactly the same as I posted above. All I want, if possible is to add a parent-category and children-category at the same time. so based on the above sample, I assume that "Animal" will have a categoryId of 1.

Comment: In that case, just use the code I provided and add 'a.ForEach(s => context.Categories.Add(s));
 context.SaveChanges();' to save it to the context

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
Category a = new Category();
Category b = new Category();

a.Children.Add(b);

context.Categories.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();
```

It does the wiring up of IDs for you.
(This is also untested.)